# error: expected primary-expression before ‘inicio’ - Erro durante a criação de objetos:

Tags: c++, classes

- OBS: Meu professor está ensinando modularização em c++, então os arquivos estão todos divididos.

Estou tentando implementar a classe point2d, mas quando tento compilar o arquivo pelo terminal do linux, ocorrem esses erros:

```
rafaelchaves:~/workspace/Lista2-TecProg/q7 (master) $ make comp
g++ q7.cpp q7classfunc.cpp -o q7 -std=c++11 && ./q7
q7.cpp:5:13: error: expected primary-expression before ‘inicio’
point2d inicio;
        ^
q7.cpp:5:13: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘inicio’
q7.cpp:5:13: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘inicio’
q7.cpp:8:1: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
}
^
make: *** [comp] Error 1
```

Abaixo o link do repositório com os códigos no github.

https://github.com/RafaelChavesPB/Lista-2--TecProg/tree/master/q7

Arquivo q7classfunc.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class point2d 
{
    protected:
        float m_x;
        float m_y;
    public:
        point2d(void);
        point2d(float newX,float newY);
        void print(void);
};
```

Arquivo q7classfunc.cpp:

```
#include "q7classfunc.h"


point2d::point2d(void){
    m_x=0;
    m_y=0;
}

point2d::point2d(float newX,float newY){
    m_x=newX;
    m_y=newY;
}

void point2d::print(){
    cout<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<"Point2d("<<m_x<<","<<m_y<<");"<<endl;
}
```

Arquivo q7.cpp:

```
#include "q7classfunc.h"

int main
{
    point2d inicio;
    point2d final(1,1);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A declaração de "main" está errada, deve ser

```
int main() // note o "()"
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: obrigado! é impressionante como um erro tão besta faz a gente perder tanto tempo kkkkk